# Configuration to tell Jekyll to avoid to apply permalink rules to files that are not markdown

Tags: jekyll

After upgrading from Jekyll 3.8 to 3.9, 4.0 or 4.1, image files in collections are processed with permalink rules.

I have this configuration

```
collections:
  arch:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path.html
```

With these files

```
image.jpeg
file.md
```

In 3.8 the output files are:

```
image.jpeg
file.html
```

After 3.8 the output files are:

```
image.html.jpeg
file.html
```

Is there a configuration to tell Jekyll to avoid to apply permalink rules to files that are not markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `.html` extension on the permalink since it is automatically generated.

```
collections:
  arch:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path
```

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: the problem is that the .url property doesn't content .html 

Comment: :output_ext could be used if required.